# Spacing in C++ using setw()

Tags: c++, spacing, setw

Here's the part of my code that I can't seem to fix the spacing for.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    cout << "Name: " << accounts[i].getName() << setw(10) << "Type: " << accounts[i].getType() << setw(10) << "Number: " << accounts[i].getAccountNumber() << setw(10) <<"Balance: " << accounts[i].getBalance() << 
    setw(10) << "Rate: " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << accounts[i].getRate() << "\n";
}
```

I can change the number in my `setw()` to make it even, but when I input different values the spacing gets messed up again.

[image: Here's the image, it's at the bottom]

Comment: The `setw` needs to go before the thing you're setting the width of.  `setw(10) << accounts[i].getName()`.

Comment: okay i'll try that